# Is a compact set C in the plane contained in an open simply connected set avoiding a point of the unbounded component of C's complement?

Tags: compactness, connectedness

How does one prove that:
*If C is a compact subset of an ordinary plane P, O a point of P belonging to the unbounded component of P\C, then there exists a simply connected open set of the plane containing C but not O*

This website shows me the following similar question already contained in it: *Finding simply connected open sets between compact ones and general open ones in R2*. That one appears similar indeed if I take in its statement U as equal to P \ {O}. But there are several differences, the main one being that my to-prove statement (above, call it Q) hasn't P\C necessarily connected. Moreover, the statement Q, implicit in the context of the proof of a theorem about complex Banach algebras (in which C is the *spectrum* of an algebra element ... which can be ANY compact set of complex numbers!) found in W.Rudin's **Functional Analysis**, seems also to be considered by Rudin as obvious - so much that he just draws my conclusion without even saying "obviously" nor giving any reference. Therefore I much prefer relatively simple answers (which is IMHO not the case for the answers given in this site to the mentioned similar statement) ... this may use really non-trivial *well-known* theorems - referred to explicitly - but little more extra arguments.

BTW I know that connected open sets in the plane are path-connected via polygonal lines & components of open sets are open (the plane being locally connected) - I imagine this can play a role in a proof.

This picture shows an example: [image: xxx]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea of the proof:

- Since $C$ is bounded, there exists $a>0$ such that $C\subset (-a,a)\times (-a,a)$.
- We know that $o$ belongs to the unbounded component of $\Bbb R^2\setminus C$. Because $\Bbb R^2\setminus C$ is open, we can find a a piecewise linear curve $P\subset \Bbb R^2\setminus C$ joining $o$ with $r=(a,a)$.
- Since $\Bbb R^2\setminus C$ is open, we can find a piecewise linear $L\subset \Bbb R^2\setminus C$ that surrounds $P$.
- Let $S=\mathrm{bd}((-a,a)\times(-a,a))$. Now we can combine $L$ with $S$ (cut them in intersection points and glue together) to obtain the piecewise linear loop that surrounds the polygon $A\supset C$ such that $o\notin \overline A$.

This of course a sketch of the proof. One has to demonstrate the existence of $L$ and the combining $L$ with $S$.

Comment: I read both answers given so far. One has been deleted in the mean time, but it gave useful aspects. Mainly that it helps to be able to use a *simple* path (in fact, a polygonal line). I posted Q elsewhere adding a picture hinting its pot. complexity incl. a NON-simple polygonal line. Trying to show how to replace such a line by a simple one - of course by induction on the number of edges of the line - seems to me now not so complicated & messy as I imagined (a think I could deliver a formal proof of it)

Comment: To Mateo: there's no hyp. that P\C is connected! But I'm nearly sure that it suffices to consider instead the unbounded component of P\C. Taking for your *P* a simple polygonal line, one should be able to construct *L* also as such a line. Taking the rad. of *S* > |r| can simplify the combining of *L* and *S* ... you get a Jordan curve, the "interior" U of which could be the needed open simply c. set, provided U is indeed simply connected! Jordan th. doesnt say that, but I read recently that there is a th. saying it is in fact homeomorphic to an open disc - this extra being false in 3D

Comment: @UlysseKeller I modified the proof so that the loop is piecewise linear loop, so the open set containing $C$ is a polygon, which is simply connected.

Comment: What about the converse? (see linked question)

Comment: I have just learned about optional things like up- and down-voting & accepting answers. And I decided to accept your answer although I hoped originally to get a more formal proof. Coming back here after months it was some work to understand what was going on here. The answer missed why the construction yields a *simply* connected open set. I saw then you have completed this in your last comment. Yes, simple polygons have a simply connected "interior" (even when not "convex" ...)