# Is the following converse of my first question true?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is the following true? *If C is a compact subset of an ordinary plane P, O a point of P , U a simply connected open set of the plane containing C but not O, then O belongs to the unbounded component of P\C.*

Case where U is bounded: there is a (far from trivial & I've not studied any proof - often the Riemann mapping theorem is used) theorem saying that then P\U is connected, therefore -  because P\C contains P\U - the conclusion follows

This does not work if U is unbounded (P\U might not be connected without the point at infinity), but we can replace U by another open set U' which is bounded and has the same other properties: one takes U' = h(U) where h: P->P' is a homeomorphism onto an open set of P obtained like this. Take P to be **R** x **R** and *I* a bounded open interval of **R** such that *I* x *I* contains C; let *J* be a compact interval contained in *I* such that *J* x *J* still contains C; there is a homeomorphism j of **R** onto *I* which is identity on *J* and one defines h by h(x,y) = (j(x),j(y)).

I am not asking for a proof, but only for confirmation or refutation of mine. In the second case, is at least the first part (for U bounded) correct?

Comment: Don't put links in the title. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469338

Comment: But you can put links in the question body.